# PhpStorm - CSS class name completion

Tags: phpstorm

I have a HTML file and a bunch of CSS files (bootstrap,.blabla,...)

On html if I call <kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd> on a "class" attribute the auto-completition work as expected.

But if in this same html file I put some `<style>` tag with some css definition, the auto-complete just work local and external css files are ignored.

Is this a OK behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes -- it's expected behaviour -- it was originally designed to behave like that (I do not remember the reasoning now (I've read about it like 3 or so years ago) -- but you may find some dev's comments about that in one of the linked tickets -- just search for ["css completion"](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB?q=%23CSS+style+completion)).

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7317 -- watch this and linked tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.